# Does Alamofire work over HTTPS network?

Tags: swift, http, https, alamofire

As the title says. Alamofire is an HTTP networking library written in Swift. But I want to know if it works over https network?

And is there any other library in swift for accessing an api and parse a json file?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#security

Answer (score 3):

As described in the official Alamofire [document](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#security) you can work also with HTTPS protocols but remember to enable NSAppTransportSecurity as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299301/1894067) (Stack Overflow answer)

[image]

P.S.: now there is the 3.4.0 version available, there is only  one issue about SSL connections, you can find [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/labels/security)

**DETAILS**:
As CouchDeveloper commented in this post , you must remember that with this configuration you actually bypass "App Transport Security", so you can control your white/black domains list in this dictionary by the NSExceptionDomains as documented in the [Apple pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016240) or in this useful page that discuss about ["Working with Apple’s App Transport Security"](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/). This documentation explain how to restrict the app network access to handle the app security settings.

Comment: With `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES` you effectively _disable_ a secure HTTPS connection and also _allow insecure_ HTTP connections. That is, you actually _bypass_ "App Transport Security" and neglect the understandable attempts from Apple to force us developers to take more responsibility for our users privacy concerns.

Comment: When you set this boolean to true you can also accept unsigned SSL certs, and this is useful when you have to work with many https servers that dont require keys. Depend by how you want to restrict your access.

Comment: No, when you set this flag to `YES` you allow insecure connections where passwords and confidential data can be send in plain text. I don't think that it is useful to bypass security checks - and thereby "pretending" to be secure. The simplest setup for a web service is to only allow HTTPS and provide a certificate whose root certificate is issued by a well known trusted CA and uses an up-to-date TLS implementation. In this case, an iOS developer benefits from the default setup on the device which is secure (as much as possible) and does not require any additional  code to make this real.

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem: many insecure HTTPS connection cannot be available if you dont change this dictionary, your app cannot connect with these servers. So you propose to configure all the https server properly so all world insecure system will be resolved. Sure it would be really cool, I'm agree with you but this is an utopia.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the info